# Why does XeTeX load bold italic instead italic?

Tags: fonts, xetex, italic

```
\font\test="IRXLotus/I" at 20pt
\test

This is a test

\bye
```

uses bold italic instead italic. what is the problem?

The font can be downloaded from [here](http://qa.parsilatex.com/28306).

Comment: Welcome! Please do not link directly to a zip. Link to the page which provides the zip, so that people can decide whether to download it. I just inadvertently downloaded it and have immediately deleted it. I don't open zips from untrusted sources and you are just a random stranger on the internet. That could be anything. If the download site is legitimate, link to the download page.

Comment: @cfr: Can you read farsi?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I can reproduce this behaviour, and a fix (at least on macOS) is to write `IRXLotus Italic` instead of `IRXLotus/I`

Comment: Looks like a bug.  LuaTeX with `luaotfload` handles it just fine.  To be honest, I cannot recommend using XeTeX to anyone these days.

Comment: @HenriMenke Unfortunately, for most of the world's scripts, XeTeX is still the only realistic option. (For example, LuaTeX does not properly support *any* Indic script except Devanagari and to some extent Malayalam.) (I've heard of LuaTeX+Harfbuzz, but not experienced it.) XeTeX is excellent in this regard; when XeTeX claims to support Unicode it really does so, unlike LuaTeX.